# Create PDF report that contains header, text and table in Perl

Tags: perl, pdf, report

I am trying to create a report with the following requirements:

1. every page will have header (something like name of the writer, date of the report).
2. Then there will be some text that describes the document (e.g name of devices, ip, etc..)
3. then there will be a table that will be few pages.

The problem I have is that whenever I am combining step 2 and 3, each one is separate page. I want the table to be just after the text.

I have tried PDF::API2, PDF::Table and PDF:Reuse (to combine the 2 parts).

Still each one of them appear on separate page. 
Any suggestions?

here is the code: 
    use PDF::API2;
    use PDF::Table;
    use PDF::Reuse;

```
my $pdftable = new PDF::Table;
my $pdf = new PDF::API2(-file => "1.pdf");
my $page = $pdf->page;

$hdr_props = 
{
        # This param could be a pdf core font or user specified TTF.
        #  See PDF::API2 FONT METHODS for more information
        font       => $pdf->corefont("Times", -encoding => "utf8"),
        font_size  => 10,
        font_color => '#006666',
        bg_color   => 'gray',
       repeat     => 1,    # 1/0 eq On/Off  if the header row should be repeated to every new       page
    };


# some data to layout
my $some_data =[
["1 Lorem ipsum dolor",
"Donec odio neque, faucibus vel",
"consequat quis, tincidunt vel, felis."],
["Nulla euismod sem eget neque.",
"Donec odio neque",
"Sed eu velit."],
["Nulla euismod sem eget neque.",
"Donec odio neque",
"Sed eu velit."],
["Nulla euismod sem eget neque.",
"Donec odio neque",
"Sed eu velit."],
["Nulla euismod sem eget neque.",
"Donec odio neque",
"Sed eu velit."],
#... and so on
];

   $left_edge_of_table = 50;
   # build the table layout
  $pdftable->table(
    # required params
    $pdf,
    $page,
    $some_data,
    x => $left_edge_of_table,
    w => 495,
    start_y => 750,
    next_y  => 700,
    start_h => 300,
    next_h  => 500,
    # some optional params
     padding => 5,
     padding_right => 10,
     background_color_odd  => shift @_ || "#FFFFFF",
     background_color_even => shift @_ || "#FFFFCC", #cell background color for even rows
     header_props   => $hdr_props, # see section HEADER ROW PROPERTIES

   );

  $pdf->saveas();



# Open an existing PDF file
$pdf = new PDF::API2(-file => "2.pdf");
$page = $pdf->page;


# Add a built-in font to the PDF
$font = $pdf->corefont('Helvetica-Bold');

# Add some text to the page
$text = $page->text();
$text->font($font, 20);
$text->translate(200, 700);
text->text('Hello World!');

  # Save the PDF
  $pdf->saveas();



prFile("report.pdf");

prDoc("2.pdf");
prDoc("1.pdf");

prEnd();
```

Comment: would (pdf-, Xe-)LaTeX work?

Comment: that's what I would recommend too.  `\usepackage{longtable}` and build it with LaTeX::Driver.

Comment: I've got PDF::API2 with a PDF::Table on the same page as text working in production. Show some code, maybe I can help you.

Comment: i have added the code...if you can look on it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents.

Reconsider your code where it says:

```
# Open an existing PDF file
$pdf = new PDF::API2(-file => "2.pdf");
$page = $pdf->page;
```

You are not about to "open an existing PDF", but you are instead defining where you'd like to be able to save your PDF (to actually save it is another task).

And then you just added a new page to it. NB: Each time you call `$pdf->page` you get a new blank page added to your PDF.

So keep working with the already defined `$page` and go ahead with PDF::Table.

Comment: Thanks. It helps. The key thought is that you need to write the text after the table (in the same page) and just play with the Y,H so it will appear before the table.